# Is there a way to show a save dialog in Electron that only allows creation?

Tags: electron

I'm building an Electron app that keeps its data in an sqlite database. I want to give the users the option to create a new database, but I don't want the create feature to overwrite an existing one. The only way I can find to prompt the user to create a file is dialog.showSaveDialog, but that also allows them to specify an existing file.

As a workaround, if the user selects an existing file, I could just show a polite "please don't do that" message, but

- that makes the user interface more confusing, and
- on my operating system (Ubuntu 22.04) there is no way to disable the follow-up "This file already exists. Do you want to replace it?" dialog, adding to the confusion.

Another workaround is to create a filter that is unlikely to select any files, but that still leaves a possibility that the user may type in the name of a file that already exists.

So is there any way to achieve what I want through the standard dialogs, or will I have to build it from scratch?